# How to display $\sqrt{-i}$ (square root of a negative imaginary) in publication?

Tags: complex-numbers

I am typing up some results in Latex, and I am tempted to include a $\sqrt{-i}$ in the publication. However, this seems ugle to me. How should it appear? Perhaps as $i\sqrt{i}$?

This is purely a style issue, I think.  Edit: This is not a style issue see the answer.

How to display $\sqrt{-i}$ (square root of a negative imaginary) in publication?

Comment: Every nonzero complex number has two square roots, opposite in sign.  Unlike the real square root case, where the convention is to use the radical $\sqrt x$ to denote the *positive* root of $x$, for general complex numbers there is no such simple convention.  Note that $\sqrt i$ may mean $\pm (1+i)(\sqrt 2/2)$.

Comment: @hardmath So $\sqrt{-i}$ is acceptable in publication?

Comment: I'm saying it is ambiguous.  It doesn't tell us *which* square root of $-i$ you mean.

Comment: If it is purely a style issue then what about a latex forum?

Comment: @PaulChilds See the answer, it is not a style issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends a lot on the context. First, it is worth noting that the element $-i\in\Bbb{C}$ has two distinct square roots in $\Bbb{C}$, so the expression $\sqrt{-i}$ does not uniquely define a complex number. So before using *any* symbol at all, I would suggest to *define* either
$$\sqrt{-i}:=\tfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}+\tfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}i
\qquad\text{ or }\qquad
\sqrt{-i}:=\tfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}-\tfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}i.$$
Then you can use whatever symbol you prefer; instead of $\sqrt{-i}$ you could use $i\sqrt{i}$ or $i^{\tfrac32}$ or $i^{3/2}$ or more concisely $\alpha$ or $\beta$ or $\gamma$, take your pick.